# specific item value not populating in correct position in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I hava a Custom Listview, the data is populating and it is working fine. In the each item i have included a like button. By Clicking the data will pass to the server and response will be returned but it is not updating in the position where i clicked and it is updating in other position. I verifying the position is correct or not before updating the text from response.

```
 private int positionOfButtonClick = -1;

 viewholder.likelay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                positionOfButtonClick = position;
                if(mp==null)
                {

                    liked(ids,user.username,ds,position);
                }
                else
                {
                    liked(ids,user.username,mp,position);
                }

            }
        });
```

The method what i am using is

```
 private void liked(final String ids, final String uname, final Activity a, final int position) {
     String UPLOAD_URL = "http://xxxxxx.com/xxxxx.php";
     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
             new Response.Listener<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String s) {
            if (positionOfButtonClick == position) {

                         if (Integer.parseInt(s) == 0) {
                             viewholder.like.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.like, 0, 0, 0);
                             viewholder.like.setText("like");

                         } else {
                             viewholder.like.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.likeblack, 0, 0, 0);
                             viewholder.like.setText(s);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
             new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                     Toast.makeText(a, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }){
         @Override
         protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
             Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
             params.put("id",ids);
             params.put("username",uname);
             return params;
         }
     };
```

what mistake am doing here?

**EDIT:**

Issue resolved as per the comment.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
             new Response.Listener<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String s) {
                   if (positionOfButtonClick == p) {
                             dusers.get(p).setLikecount(Integer.parseInt(s));
                             if(dusers.get(p).getLike() == 1)
                             {
                                 dusers.get(p).setLike(0);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 dusers.get(p).setLike(1);
                             }
                             notifyDataSetChanged();

                     }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: on Server response, update your `list`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: After getting the response from server in onResponse(String s) method, update that object in the data list (ArrayList/List/HashMap whatever you are using) and call notifyDataSetChanged() after that.

Comment: dusers.get(p).likecount  = Integer.parseInt(s);  notifyDataSetChanged(); i modified like this but it affects all the values.